# is there any impact in performance when we need to access last sort key for any particular partition key

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I am creating a dynamoDB table. I am using an custromerId as partition key and versionNumber as sort key. suppose there are 1000 versions for any particular customerId. for my use-case I always want to find out last version of any customerId. will there be any difference in performance when i want first versionNumber and when i want last versionNumber or both will take same time.

Answer (score 1):

No, actually we'll have a parameter ScanIndexForward (True/False). So based on this it starts reading the dynamoDB in ascending or the descending order.

Comment: so now that the parameter is added, is there any performance/time/cost penalty for using `ScanIndexForward`?